# How to get the mean price of every book in json with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

As shown in the following, it's a json contain books data.The book store would adjust the book price throughout every year. The goal is to get the every year mean of the book price for every book and display them in a table.

**Json**

```
[
 {
   "Year":"2009",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Happy Prince"
   "Book price":"10"  
},
 {
   "Year":"2009",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Happy Prince"
   "Book price":"14"
 
},
  "Year":"2009",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Happy Prince"
   "Book price":"13"
}, 

"Year":"2009",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Jane"
   "Book price":"10"  
}, 
"Year":"2009",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Jane"
   "Book price":"12"  
},

"Year":"2010",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Happy Prince"
   "Book price":"15"  
}, 

"Year":"2010",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Happy Prince"
   "Book price":"10"  
},

"Year":"2010",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Jane"
   "Book price":"15"
   
},

"Year":"2010",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Jane"
   "Book price":"11"  
},
]
```

Table showing annual mean price for every book
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass to `DataFrame` constructor then use `groupby`, notice here we have numeric column as string type ,so we need to convert it back before use `mean` function

```
out = pd.DataFrame(j).groupby(['Year','Book name'],as_index=False)[['Book price']].agg(lambda x : x.astype(int).mean())
out
Out[348]: 
   Year     Book name  Book price
0  2009  Happy Prince   12.333333
1  2009          Jane   11.000000
2  2010  Happy Prince   12.500000
3  2010          Jane   13.000000
```

Data Fix and input

```
j = [
 {
   "Year":"2009",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Happy Prince",
   "Book price":"10"  
},
 {
   "Year":"2009",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Happy Prince",
   "Book price":"14"
 
},
    { "Year":"2009",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Happy Prince",
   "Book price":"13"
}, 
    {"Year":"2009",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Jane",
   "Book price":"10"  
}, 
    {"Year":"2009",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Jane",
   "Book price":"12"  
},
    {"Year":"2010",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Happy Prince",
   "Book price":"15"  
}, 
    {"Year":"2010",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Happy Prince",
   "Book price":"10"  
},
    {"Year":"2010",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Jane",
   "Book price":"15"
   
},
    {"Year":"2010",
   "Book store":"ABC Store",
   "Book name":"Jane",
   "Book price":"11"  
},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to BENY's you can do it using pivot table too (which was the example i was giving, before BENY answered as I was too busy trying to fix the json :-))

So I thought it might worth sharing it anyway

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Year','Book name'], values='Book price', aggfunc=np.mean)

                   Book price
Year Book name
2009 Happy Prince   12.333333
     Jane           11.000000
2010 Happy Prince   12.500000
     Jane           13.000000
```